# windows batch command "==" operator weird behavior

Tags: windows, batch-file, jenkins, command-prompt

I have a windows batch command in jenkins :

```
set /p Build=<version.txt
IF ("%Build%"=="%VERSION%") (echo version doesn't match)
IF NOT ("%Build%"=="%VERSION%") (echo version match)
```

where Build and VERSION are got from the build. The output of the above is

```
w:\ce-billing-release>set /p Build= 0<version.txt 
w:\ce-billing-release>IF ("1.1.0" == "1.1.0") (echo version match ) 
w:\ce-billing-release>IF NOT ("1.1.0" == "1.1.0") (echo version doesn't match ) 
version doesn't match
```

Even though it gets the right value of both the variable = 1.1.0 , for some reason it thinks they are not equal. What am I missing ?

Answer (score 3):

Don't use `()` to delimit the comparison. `()` aren't meaningful to `if`, and will become PART of the string being compared:

```
C:\Users\marc>IF ("1.1.0" equ "1.1.0") (echo version match )

C:\Users\marc>IF "1.1.0" equ "1.1.0" (echo version match )
version match
```